# How do I gift the rewards of the Bioshock Infinite pre-order?

Tags: steam

I pre-purchased [Bioshock Infinite](http://store.steampowered.com/app/8870/). Along with this, I received Bioshock and X-Com. Both I have already. On the store-page it says for both games:

> Already own it on Steam? Gift it to a friend

How can I gift this to a friend then?

Thanks!

Comment: Do they show up in your Steam Inventory? They should show up in a gifts section or something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any games you receive additional copies of will appear in your Steam Inventory. You can access your Steam Inventory by clicking on the *View* menu followed by *Inventory*, or clicking on the 'envelope' on the Steam titlebar;

[image]

This will bring up your Steam inventory;

[image]

From here you can select any item and send it to a friend, either by using their Steam account name or email address.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. You need to go the menu point "View" - "Inventory". There you have all games which you can give to someone else.